# Using localizable file in private pod for main project in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, localization, cocoapods

I'm making a project and creating some private pods to handle Authentication, Networking... And using SwiftGen framework

Now my app requires to support multi-language for English and Japanese for users can change it on the fly. And I realize that the pods don't change the language whenever I switch between Eng or Jap because I create localizable for each of them.

So I wonder that is there any way to use just one `Localizable.strings` file for the main project and other private pods? I was thinking about creating a Core module then putting the localizable file into it. But don't know how to read the file from main project and other private pods.

Can anyone gimme advice?